# Anchor doesn't work if it's given in the url

Tags: links

I'm trying to link to a specific part of the page, but when I include anchor in the URL, server doesn't interpret it, so I'm not sure how I would go to the anchor.

If I go to
http://www.exlogue.com/?page_id=55

And pick "French", the following url is produced:
http://www.exlogue.com/?page_id=55#french

But if I try to open that link in a new tab, then I just see the initial page.(the one without anchor) I want to be able to get to the anchor from another page.

Is there another way to go the anchor by modifying the URL or the code for that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Anchor will never get to your server, it is only for client use (your browser). PHP will never get the anchor, and will do nothing with it. This is more Browser related, than Wordpress or Server related.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I asked in WordPress to see if there is an alternative way to get to those anchors(as if I clicked a button on that page from another page)